# Method's Curly brackets do not match when code to long

Tags: c++, gedit, geany

I have a C++ method with multiple nested "if statements" which are enclosed in the curly brackets of the method.  When using Gedit's matching curly brackets, I was checking to ensure that all my curly brackets were correctly matched.

Problem:  Gedit stated that my last two curly brackets were " out of range"!
I checked same code using Geany, and it showed correct matches for all my curly brackets.

However, when compiling, the method's local variables defined at the beginning of the method, were not recognized within some latter written nested "if statements" within the method.    Is there  a limit of the number line codes contained between curly brackets?  Or, is there a limit of nested "if and else if statements" that would cause this problem?

Comment: Show the code. Nobody here has a crystal bowl to see the problem

Comment: I don't believe there's any specified limit on nested blocks, however it really sounds like your code could do with [refactorisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

Comment: Formally not, but the fact that you need to ask is a clear sign that your function is too long and complex.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of lines of code contained between the brackets, also there is no limit for the 'else if' ladder.

try using switch-case statements if you can.

Comment: Code cannot be easily shorten. I'm loading a linklist where each node has 4 parameters, A, B, C and D. I order all nodes according to assending sizes of A.  For all A's with the same size, I order the same nodes to different sizes to B and this goes on for C and D the same way.  So, I have a lot of if and else statements.

Comment: @vathsa There are obviously limits to both, because the compiler only has a finite amount of memory to work with.  Given the way compilers work, where each `else if` in the ladder is considered an additional level of nesting, the limit can be surprisingly low.  (Annex B of the standard suggests that it should be at least 256; I'd expect something in the thousands, if not more, from a modern compiler.)  But of course, if he exceeds the limit, the compiler _should_ output an error message (but I'll but that this hasn't been tested by the compiler writers).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit of the number line codes contained between curly brackets?

Only available disk space and memory.

> Or, is there a limit of nested "if and else if statements" that would cause this problem?

Ditto.

Clearly you are mistaken about your braces matching. If you have a method that is so long you can't be sure, refactor it.

Answer (score 1):

There are obviously limits, since the compiler has to keep track
of everything in memory, and memory is finite.  I've actually
had an out of memory error with g++ (with machine generated
code).  Reaching the limit should result in a compile time
error, however.

Practically, for hand written code, you can consider that there
are no limits on a modern machine.  You generally shouldn't have
more than about ten or fifteen lines in a function (although
there are exceptions), and you shouldn't nest more than about
two levels.  Of course, one of the cases where more lines might
be justified is a long sequence of `if`/`else if`, and in the
case of `if`/`else if`, the compiler sees more levels of nesting
than you do.  But I would still expect a modern compiler on
a modern machine to handle a couple of hundred `if`/`else if`
without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been discussed here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1175657

It seems there is indeed a limit on the number of characters that are being searched for finding the match.